# Is there a difference if I use excess "const" keywords?

Tags: flutter, dart

Building flutter apps is all about code efficiency. Of course, when building a reactive application I would use "const" before widgets and classes with constant constructors. However, I would like to know if there is any PERFORMANCE and APP SIZE difference between the following examples:

```dart
const List<Color> colors = <Color>[
  Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
  Color(0xFF000000),
];
```

and

```dart
const List<Color> colors = <Color>[
  const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
  const Color(0xFF000000),
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Since Dart 2.0, these redundant const keywords are optional.

So:

```dart
const foo = <T>[ Foo() ];
```

is strictly equivalent to:

```dart
const foo = const <T>[ const Foo() ];
```

Comment: Alright, that's great. Thank you. I'll avoid these redundant keywords from now on.
But do these excess keywords anyhow affect the size of the APK? In DEX files, for instance?
Of course if it would be the matter of some bytes, but any small mistakes snowball in big flutter apps.

Comment: No. This has no impact whatsoever. This is only a syntax sugar. They compile to the same thing

Comment: Thank you, you are awesome. Will accept when stackoveflow's 15 min limit passes.